# Dropdownlist values based on another dropdown list

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdownlist control in which i have added two list items.Both these list items are added manually by me and not from any database.Based on the selection i would like to show another dropdownlist which has a sqldatasource.

I am able to accomplish this if my intial dropdownlist source is also from a database
how do i accomplish this from reading the value of the dropdownlist and populating another dropdown based on the selected value

The second dropdownlist that needs to be populated is going to vary(from differant tables) based on the selected value in the first dropdownlist

Need direction ideas please

Thanks

Comment: Give us the code you are dealing with please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  protected void dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     string val = dropdown1.SelectedItem.Value;
     if(val == "xyz")
       SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "Select * From Table_1";
     else if(val == "abc")
       SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "Select * From Table_2";

      SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
  }
```